# Pointless USB on my Apple Monitor?

Tags: display

I have an external Apple Display monitor wit x3 USB ports on the back. They dont charge my phone at all, or do anything at all as far as I can figure out. How can i use them?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). Regarding your question, can you please provide the exact model details of the Apple Display in question?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Thunderbolt displays, which can be commonly solved by resetting the [System Management Controller](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).